# Have problem with deploying django using apache

Tags: django, apache, deployment, httpd.conf

Hello I am having a problem with Django trying to get it deployed on a server using apache. for some reason when I write this information in my httpd.conf file.

```
<location "/mysite">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
    PythonOption django.root /mysite
    PythonDebug off
    PythonPath "['/user/local/src/djcode','/user/local/src/djcode/mysite'] + sys.path"
</Location>
```

I get this error when I restart apache.

```
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'PythonHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed mod_python http://www.modpython.org/?

Comment: Now I think about it, when I go to my modules folder. I do not have mod_python.so iin my modules folder. This may be the problem.

Comment: I have installed mod_python.so using all default configurations. I cannot see in in /usr/local/apache2/modules/. It is not even in /usr/lib/apache2/modules. so when I restart apache it gives the same error undefined.

Comment: Ok I have finally installed it. But my god thee where to many problems I had installing it. One I need a lot of lib and binary like flex. Also I did not knew but I realised there was a problem with the source code so if I did not go to this page I think I would not have been able to do it.https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MODPYTHON-249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error is pretty much self explanatory (second line is important to you):

```
Invalid command 'PythonHandler', perhaps misspelled 
or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

PythonHandler is a command unknown by apache. it's a "module command" known by mod_python. so if missing it says invalid command (OR defined by module not in...).

so make sure mod_python is installed.

you might know it anyways, but just follow this document http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/

Comment: On Centos, `yum install mod_python` worked for me and got me past this error.

Answer (score 1):

Also, i recommend you use [mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) instead of mod_python. See deprecation warning on top of this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modpython/

> Support for mod_python will be
>   deprecated in a future release of
>   Django. If you are configuring a new
>   deployment, you are strongly
>   encouraged to consider using mod_wsgi
>   or any of the other supported
>   backends.

Answer (score 1):

`python_mod` is not installed or not configured in `httpd.conf`.
If you have installed it, then add this line below in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
```